# JSSOR - does lazyloading actually work?

Tags: jssor

I would like to know does lazyloading option actually work and how do I verify it. On all my browser, i can see that it actually loads all images at once while the page is loading and not when needed. It does allow me to scroll through even when my images are loading. Each of my images are roughly between 400kb-600kb.

Rgds,
Kong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does work.

By default, the $LazyLoading option value is 1. That's to say, it will load image for current slide and 1 adjacent slide.

You can manually set $LazyLoading value to 0, in this manner, it will load image for current slide only.

btw, please make sure you replaced src="url' with src2="url" for all images.

Comment: Thanks. Will do and get back to you.

Comment: it works better now. thanks. there was a conflict with another lazyloader that i added.

Comment: It's the src to src2 change that I overlooked, works fine now. Thanks.