# How can I prevent preloading of images in jssor?

Tags: image, jssor, preloading

Using jssor with sliders on my website (http://www.skysurfer.eu) with astrophotos, on load ALL photos are loaded totalling 9 MB which is not a problem for me but with slow internet (or expensive 3G or 4G internet) it is.
As there in only one image shown at a time (preloading of thumbnails is OK of course), at opening of the site, only the first image should be loaded and the subsequent only loaded one by one when clicking on the arrows or thumbnails. Autoplay is off.

How can I disable this preloading of all images ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

I did not know whether this option was called 'lazyloading' and the IMG tag should be loaded with  rather than src.

[JSSOR - does lazyloading actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238283/jssor-does-lazyloading-actually-work)